# Forbidden 403: CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: python, html, django, csrf, http-status-code-403

I keep getting this error when submitting a POST request with a form:

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

and then it says that the CSRF token missing or incorrect. I definitely included the token in my html, and here's my views method:

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TextForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/texts')
    else:
        form = TextForm()   
    return render_to_response('texts/index.html', {'form': form}, 
                        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

What am I doing wrong?? I've tried a bunch of different things but nothing is fixing it.

Here's the index.html:

```
<h1> Texts </h1>
<form action="/texts/create/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<hr>
```

Comment: have you added `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` to your list of middlewares ?

Comment: yes I have that included in my settings file for the entire project

Comment: @Joshin did you check the HTML output to see if csrf_token is included in rendered HTML?

Comment: Yes when I load just the html I can see the {% csrf_token %} , but when I load the webpage before posting and check with chrome devtools I can't see it.

Comment: remove `action="/texts/create/"` from `form` tag, because the same view render GET and POST

Comment: @Joshin: if you can't see it with chrome devtools, it's not there, and there is some reason why it's not using that template. Try changing something else (like the "Texts" header) and see if it has an effect.